# Binding data to a grid control on a separate thread

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am using Tasks to fetch data on a separate thread so that the user can continue using the application.  The problem I found is that the actual binding of my data to my grid also takes a few seconds.  How can I bind my data on the same thread as my FetchData() call?

```
Task<List<SomeData>> getData = new Task<List<SomeData>>(() =>
{
    List<SomeData> myData = FetchData(); // Expensive!
    return myData;
});

getData.Start();

Task processData = getData.ContinueWith(data =>
{
    grid.DataSource = data; // Takes a few second so now the UI thread is disrupted
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // UI thread :(
```

Comment: What are you using? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: WinForms.  Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Are you sure there's no deferred execution issue?  How many objects are in the data?

Comment: As an example, if you're using an ORM with lazy loading enabled, the actual bind would be when it made the calls to load child entities that you didn't eager-load

Comment: I'm not using an ORM.  It is simply a List of some basic objects that gets bound to the grid.  There are a couple of thousand rows... hence the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `BackgroundWorker`? Just pull the backgroundworker from toolbox into the form, then start the process with BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerAsync call.

In the `DoWork` event, do the data fetching.

In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, bind the results to grid.

Comment: This does not help. The main thread will still get stuck on the RunWorkerCompleted event